# Make a class injectable and a singleton with Dagger annotation only

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I know there are tutorials of how to define singleton with `Module`. But my question is not really on that. I mean Dagger also provides a way to make a class injectable to Android component by annotate that class's empty constructor without declare anything in `Module`, right? e.g.

```
public class MyApi {

    @Inject
    public MyApi(){
    }
}
```

So, I can inject `MyApi` to an `Fragment` by :

```
class MyFragment extends Fragment {
   @Inject
   protected MyApi myApi;
   ...
}
```

In this way, `MyApi` doesn't need to be manually declared in `Module`. Dagger understands it.

My question is if I want `MyApi` to be a singleton, could I simply add one more annotation like:

```
public class MyApi {
    @Inject
    @Singleton
    public MyApi(){
    }
}
```

Would dagger understand it is supposed to be a singleton? Or Do I have to declare in `Module` like:

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MyApi providesMyApi() {
        return new MyApi();
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `@Singleton` on top of the class.

```
@Singleton
public class MyApi {
    @Inject
    public MyApi() {}
 }
```

Second, you will need to add `@Singleton` on top of your `component` interface.

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {
```

Here is a completed guide in kotlin if you are interested: https://medium.com/@xiwei/simplest-dagger-example-920bbd10258

Comment: Does the `@Singleton` annotation on top of `AppComponent` makes all object injected to the declared class (e.g. Activity) singleton? What if I would like to have some object injects to Activity singleton while some are not? I don't get why I have to have the whole AppComponent declared singleton.

Comment: @leem It doesn't make all object singleton, only those declared as Singleton. Adding it to Component seems to be an unnecessary overhead in Dagger. Maybe it's just there to declare `There might be Singletons in this component`.

Comment: That's right. If you have a MyApplicationComponent, and it injects MyActivityComponent, and MyActivityComponent injects a class MyClass marked `@Singleton`, which Component does MyClass get stored in? If you mark the component, it's clear; if you don't, Dagger won't know which Component is supposed to hold `@Singleton`s.

Answer (score 0):

for desired behaviour, you need to apply annotation on the class, not constructor. take a look:

```
 @Singleton
 public class MyApi {

     @Inject
     public MyApi(){
     }
 }
```

Comment: I get weird compiler error after adding the @Singleton above class name.

Comment: `org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:37)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
 at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
)
`

Comment: Without the `@Singleton`, the compilation error doesn't appear.